# Properly animating circle radius with CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, cabasicanimation

I want to expand and contract a circle using `CABasicAnimation`. I previously designed a clean and effective way to draw the animation using `sin` and the `drawRect` method of the `UIView` class, but unfortunately it seems you can't animate or force `drawRect` to fire in `UIView.animate` methods no matter what you do. Therefore, I've had to come up with a workaround using `CABasicAnimation`. The result kind of works, but the animation is ugly and doesn't look right. Here's an illustration of what I mean:

[image]

Warping occurs during the expansion and contraction, and there appears to be a dent or cavity on the right side when the circle is expanding. Here's the class responsible for animating it:

```
struct PathConfig {
    var arcCenter: CGPoint
    var radius: CGFloat
    let startAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
    let endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(2 * M_PI)
}

class RGSStandbyIndicatorView: UIView {

    // MARK: - Variables & Constants

    /// The drawing layer.
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    // MARK: - Class Methods

    /// Animation function.
    func animate(period: CFTimeInterval) {
        let p: PathConfig = PathConfig(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2) , radius: 17.5)
        let b: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: p.arcCenter, radius: p.radius, startAngle: p.startAngle, endAngle: p.endAngle, clockwise: true)
        let a: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")

        a.fromValue = shapeLayer.path
        a.toValue = b.cgPath
        a.autoreverses = true
        a.duration = period
        a.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        a.repeatCount = HUGE
        shapeLayer.add(a, forKey: "animateRadius")
    }

    /// Initializes and returns a CAShapeLayer with the given draw path and fill color.
    private class func shapeLayerForPath(_ path: CGPath, with fillColor: CGColor) -> CAShapeLayer {
        let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor
        return shapeLayer
    }

    /// Configures the UIView
    private func setup() {

        // Init config, path.
        let cfg: PathConfig = PathConfig(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2) , radius: 0.0)
        let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: cfg.arcCenter, radius: cfg.radius, startAngle: cfg.startAngle, endAngle: cfg.endAngle, clockwise: true)

        // Init CAShapeLayer
        shapeLayer = RGSStandbyIndicatorView.shapeLayerForPath(path.cgPath, with: UIColor.white.cgColor)

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    // MARK: Class Method Overrides

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

}
```

I've tried adjusting the start and end angles hoping it was some artifact of the path having no overlap, but it didn't change anything. I'm not sure how to fix this problem, and It's based off Chadwick Wood's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36770729/2100609) to a similar question.

Comment: Why you don´t use CGAffineTransform.scale and make your view rounded by corner radius?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this UIView subclass**

```
class RadioAnimationView: UIView {

    var animatableLayer : CAShapeLayer?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height/2

        self.animatableLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        self.animatableLayer?.fillColor = self.backgroundColor?.cgColor
        self.animatableLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        self.animatableLayer?.frame = self.bounds
        self.animatableLayer?.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height/2
        self.animatableLayer?.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.animatableLayer!)
        self.startAnimation()
    }


    func startAnimation()
    {
        let layerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        layerAnimation.fromValue = 1
        layerAnimation.toValue = 3
        layerAnimation.isAdditive = false
        layerAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(2)
        layerAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        layerAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        layerAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
        layerAnimation.autoreverses = true

        self.animatableLayer?.add(layerAnimation, forKey: "growingAnimation")
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot better than my current attempt. It solved my problem. I honestly didn't know anything about CAAffineTransform. I've been trying to get some animations done this afternoon for the first time and was tunneled in on CABasicAnimation I guess.

Comment: @Owatch you approach is valid but you need to use a helper function to get proper path in every space of time modifiying the radius of the arc, I have done this before buf its over complicated for your current needs so I think this is a better approach for you, I am glad to help you, Happy coding and best regards